# Want to take a sentence input of words separated by hyphen. Then sort the words in sentence alphabatically and return sentence in same hyphen format?

Tags: c++

Example:
Input: this-is-a-sentence
Output: a-is-sentence-the

I am learning C++ so don't know what approach should I use there is time and space constraints.
Here is my code by far:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    string words[10];
    int j = 0;
    string str = "A-computer-science-portal-for-geeks";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '-') {
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    stringstream ssin(str);
    while (ssin.good() && j < str.length()){
        ssin >> words[j];
        ++j;
    }
    sort(words,words+str.length(),greater<int>()); 
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I did is took string input replaced all Hyphens(-) with Space. Saw this sstream method in internet used it to separate the words and append words to array. Now I just have to sort array and return it in hyphen format.

Or just suggest some easy method to do so plz.
I can do it Python but in C++ its bit difficult for me! :)

Comment: what are the time and space constraints? What is the question? Is your code not working? Compiler error? Wrong output?

Comment: `sort(words,words+str.length(),greater<int>()); ` is completely wrong and doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Can your input have more than 10 words in it?

Comment: PS: don't try to learn C++ from "competetive coding" sites. You have picked up a number of habits that make you a *worse* C++ programmer than someone who has zero experience with C++

Answer (score 1):

First things first, change this:

```cpp
std::sort(words, words + str.length(), std::greater<int>());
```

which is wrong in many ways, since size of the array `words` is `10`, but the length of `str` in this case is `35` which is outside the bounds of `words`, so essentially *undefined behavior*. In addition, `std::greater<int>()` is for integers, not for strings.

Consider changing it to this:

```cpp
// The below line will sort 'words' in lexicographic order followed by empty strings
std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [] (std::string const& a, std::string const& b) {
                                                  return a < b && a != "";
                                              });
```

This will sort the array of strings properly.

Secondly, look at this snippet:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    if (str[i] == '-')
        str[i] = ' ';

std::stringstream ssin(str);
while (ssin.good() && j < str.length()){
    ssin >> words[j];
    ++j;
}
```

Now, the above is inefficient as you would need to convert all the hyphens into spaces by iterating through the whole string and *then proceed to extract the words from the string*. Moreover, this snippet is also prone to *undefined behavior* for the same reason as above. (Because of `j < str.length()`)

Instead, you can just directly extract the words from the string using [`std::getline(ssin, words[j], '-')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```cpp
std::stringstream ssin(str);
// Extracts all words separated by '-' and puts them inside 'words'
for (int j = 0; std::getline(ssin, words[j], '-'); j++);
```

---

***Final runnable code:***

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
 
int main(){
    std::string words[10] = {};
    std::string str = "A-computer-science-portal-for-geeks";
    
    std::stringstream ssin(str);
    for (int j = 0; std::getline(ssin, words[j], '-'); j++);

    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [] (std::string const& a, std::string const& b) {
                                                      return a < b && a != "";
                                                  });

    for (auto it = std::begin(words); it != std::prev(std::end(words)); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << (std::next(it)->empty() ? "" : "-");
}
```

---

Do note that the behavior of the above program is undefined when your string contains more than 10 words separated by hyphens. Consider increasing that limit if needed, or just use [`std::vector<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which resizes dynamically:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string str = "A-computer-science-portal-for-geeks";
    
    std::stringstream ssin(str);
    while (std::getline(ssin, [&words] () -> std::string& {
                                  words.emplace_back();
                                  return *words.rbegin();
                              }(), '-'));

    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [] (std::string const& a, std::string const& b) {
                                                      return a < b && a != "";
                                                  });

    for (auto it = std::begin(words); it != std::prev(std::end(words)); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << (std::next(it)->empty() ? "" : "-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sort(words,words+str.length(),greater<int>());
```

First of all, you're passing `greater<int>()` which is a struct object with `()` operator overload that compares two `int`s as `(first > second)` but your array is of `std::string` so `greater<std::string>()` is what you should be using. Or you could just use `std::greater<>()` and let the comparison call deduce the type.

Second, `str.length()` is the number of characters in `str`, not the words. So you should use `sort(words, words + count_of_words, std::greater<>())` instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    cout << words[i] << endl;
}
```

Same in last loop, you're accessing out of bounds and invoking undefined behavior as `str.length()` > `10`. It should be `i < count_of_words`.

You can use `j` as `count_of_words` here resulting in:

```
sort(words, words + j,std::greater<>());
for(int i = 0;i < j;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe too advanced for you, but I would like to show it to you anyway.

Maybe you can get a better understanding of the power of modern C++. Modern C++ has many predefined library functions. You can look in CPP reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for details. But sometimes it is hard to understand for starters.

Basically, just 3 lines of code are necessary.

Let us divide your problem in smaller parts. You want to split a sentence in smaller parts (words). The parts(words) are separated by a hyphen (-). The resulting words need to be stored somewhere.

To drill down further, you need a “storage”. You have chosen a fixed size C-style array with 10 elements. That will work for your approach, but in general not. Because it has a fixed size and cannot grow dynamically. What is the solution? The `std::vector`. It is the common solution for dynamic growable storage areas and used everywhere. The usage is quite similar to a C-style array, but it is much more powerful. And best of all. It grows as needed. Dynamically.

Additionally it has many constructors, that help to initialize elements of the `std::vector`. One of them is a constructor that is taking a `begin` and an `end` `iterator`. And it will initialize the elements of the `std::vector` with all elements pointed to and in the range of the iterators.

Good, next. Splitting a string. That is a very old and common task. Often it is called “Tokenize”, because we will split a string into Tokens. And the tokens can be specified using patterns. And patterns can be specified using regular expressions. And those are available as `std::regex`.

Putting all this together, we can define a `std::vector` as

```
std::vector words
```

and initialize it with iterators. And we will use the `std::sregex_token_iterator` for that. It will iterate over all words, or, in our case, over all “things” separated by a hyphen.

So,

```
std::vector words(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), separator, -1), {});
```

Will split the text into words and store the results in the `std::vector`. By the way. In this case the `std::vector` does not need a type (like std::string), because the type can be deduced from the parameters. This is a C++17 feature and called CTAD.

The next step is really easy. Sorting the words. We will simply use the available `std::sort` function. I guess, no further explanation necessary.

And last but not least, we want to show the result to the user.

Also, for output activities, we have an iterator. The `std::ostream_iterator` will output anything for us. With that, we can simply “copy” (using `std::copy`) all words to `std::cout`. The copy-function will simply “invoke” the iterator, and this guy will output the current value.

Because we do not want an hyphen at the very end of the output, we use a `std::ostream_joiner` which works like the before, but omits the last hyphen.

Then, finally, we get the following example code:

```
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

const std::regex separator{R"(-)"};
const std::string test {"A-computer-science-portal-for-geeks"};

int main() {

    std::vector words(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), separator, -1), {});
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, "-"));

    return 0;
}
```

This program has been compiled and tested with

X86-64 GCC 11.2 and x86-64 clang 12.01.1 using C++ 17 language (-std=c++17)

on site: Compiler Explorer (godbolt.org)